# Special function generating function

Tags: special-functions

Can this be represented as linear combinations of complex exponential: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-(e^{(i\theta)}+e^{-i\theta})t+t^2)}}$. This is the generating function of Legendre polynomials $P_l(cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Is $\frac{1}{1-e^{i\theta}t}$ a linear combination of complex exponentials?

Comment: What are your intention?

Comment: I will post a solution, you can check if it is correct.